# WP7 TextBlock inside a ListBox not wrapping text

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, textblock

I have a `ListBox` which has `StackPanel`s holding a `TextBlock` and an `Image` horizontally, followed by a `ContentPresenter`. This is what the XAML looks like:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox"
           Margin="12,0,12,0"
           SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

        <StackPanel>
          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu"
                                 Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
              <toolkit:MenuItem Header="edit"
                                Tag="edit"
                                Click="MenuItem_Click" />
              <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete"
                                Tag="delete"
                                Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
          </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">

            <!-- **** This text won't wrap **** -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />

            <Image Source="/image.png"
                   Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}" />

          </StackPanel>

          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        </StackPanel>

      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I'm setting the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection` within the page constructor. Everything works fine until the `Header` text becomes too long, in which case it is not wrapping as I've specified it to. How can I force the `TextBlock` to wrap the text?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely a result of not restricting the width of the TextBlock, so it is growing horizontaly off screen where you can't see it.

Comment: But shouldn't the TextWrapping property take care of that? Is there any other way to solve this problem? For instance, using Grids instead of StackPanels to hold the UIElements.

Comment: I'm not sure how the TextWrapping would know what the horizontal boundary is if it isn't somehow constrained.

Comment: You were right, I fixed the problem by adding a `SizeChanged` event to the `TextBox` and setting its width based on the page width.